# Angular router queryParamsHandling: 'preserve' not working

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am using the following `navigate` call:

```typescript
this.router.navigate([''], { queryParamsHandling: 'preserve' });
```

When I call my app using /?timeout=true the queryParams get removed.
If I pass them using my manual parsing it works:

```typescript
const url = window.location.href;
const params = url.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1)
                  .split('&')
                  // tslint:disable:no-any
                  .reduce((params: any, param) => {
                      const [key, value] = param.split('=');
                      params[key] = value ? decodeURIComponent(value.replace(/\+/g, ' ')) : '';
                      return params;
                  }, {}) : {};
this.router.navigate([''], params);
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: queryParams get removed ? what does it mean?

Comment: When I call the page with `/?timeout=true`, the ?timeout=true is gone after calling `this.router.navigate([''], { queryParamsHandling: 'preserve' });`

Comment: for me this.router.navigate([''], { queryParamsHandling: 'preserve' }); is working fine. If possible can you please reproduce your behavior on stackblitz or fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was overridden by a Navigation Guard I didn't know of. Fixed it by now by changing how the initial navigation is done, putting a `QueryParamService` I wrote before it.